# I need to compare COUNT() results in Access SQL and perform functions based on the result

Tags: sql, select, count, max, distinct

I have the following tables:

```
   VENDOR:          PRODUCT:           ITEM:             STORE:
-  VENDOR_ID     -  PRODUCT_ID      -  ITEM_ID        -  STORE_ID
-  VENDOR_NAME   -  PRODUCT_DESC    -  STORE_ID       -  STORE_NAME
                 -  VENDOR_ID       -  PRODUCT_ID     -  STORE_LOCATION
                                    -  ITEM_PRICE
```

The VENDOR table stores information about the product's vendor, the PRODUCT table stores information about the products, the ITEM table is essentially the inventory of the store, with a record for each item that is in stock. If there is more than one of the same product in the item inventory, it has a different ITEM_ID, but ITEM_ID and PRODUCT_ID are the primary key. The STORE stores store information :D

I want to list the names of the vendors who provide products to the store that has the greatest range of products. So, I think I'll need to use a COUNT function to count the number of distinct PRODUCT_IDs in each STORE's ITEM records.

I don't really know how to get started on this, I would appreciate a bit of help.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VENDOR.VENDOR_NAME AS [Vendor Name]
FROM VENDOR, PRODUCT, ITEM, STORE
WHERE STORE.STORE_ID 
IN (SELECT STORE_ID 
FROM ITEM);
```

This returns all the vendors, but I need to add a COUNT or MAX function in there, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) and [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp)

Comment: I have posted the solution below. Please try this if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT V.VENDOR_NAME, COUNT(I.PRODUCT_ID)
FROM ((VENDOR AS V 
INNER JOIN PRODUCT AS P ON V.VENDOR_ID = P.VENDOR_ID) 
INNER JOIN ITEM AS I ON P.PRODUCT_ID = I.PRODUCT_ID) 
INNER JOIN STORE AS S ON I.STORE_ID = S.STORE_ID 
WHERE S.STORE_NAME = 'Store Name"
GROUP BY V.VENDOR_NAME
ORDER BY COUNT(I.PRODUCT_ID) DESC
```

The above query will get the vendor's name and a count of the product ids.  I put the WHERE clause in there so you could specify a certain store.  If you want all stores then remove the WHERE.

Comment: might want to explain what you have done. So the OP has more understanding.

Comment: I'm using Access SQL, I don't think that the JOIN function works in that. I tried INNER JOIN, but it throws a syntax error. Do you know how I can overcome this?

Comment: I modified my answer so it would work in Access.  Access requires some parenthesis in the JOIN statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Z.VENDOR_NAME AS VENDOR_NAME
FROM
(
    SELECT B.PRODUCT_ID,A.STORE_ID 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT A.STORE_ID,MAX(COUNT_PRODUCTS_PER_EACH_STORE) AS MAX_COUNT_PRODUCTS_PER_EACH_STORE
      FROM
      (
       SELECT STORE_ID,COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) AS COUNT_PRODUCTS_PER_EACH_STORE
       FROM ITEM
       GROUP BY STORE_ID
      ) A
    ) A,
    ITEM B
    WHERE A.STORE_ID = B.STORE_ID
) X,
PRODUCT Y,
VENDOR Z
WHERE X.PRODUCT_ID = Y.PRODUCT_ID
  AND Y.VENDOR_ID = Z.VENDOR_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

To break it down you first want to get "the store that has the greatest range of products", since access doesn't allow `COUNT(DISTINCT` you need to use a subquery to get distinct records before counting:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 
        Store_ID,
        COUNT(Product_ID) AS StoreProducts
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT Store_ID, Product_ID
            FROM    Item
        ) i
GROUP BY Store_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(Product_ID) DESC;
```

This returns the store_ID of the store that has the highest number of distinct products.

Then you need to get all the vendor_IDs that supply products to any given store (and the number of products supplied if required)

```
SELECT  Item.Store_ID, 
        Vendor.Vendor_ID, 
        Vendor.Vendor_Name, 
        COUNT(Product.Product_ID) AS ItemsSuppliedToStore
FROM    (Item
        INNER JOIN Product
            ON item.Product_ID = Product.Product_ID)
        INNER JOIN Vendor
            ON Vendor.Vendor_ID = Product.Vendor_ID
GROUP BY Item.Store_ID, Vendor.Vendor_ID, Vendor.Vendor_Name;
```

This will give you all venders by store_ID and the number of items they have at that store

Then you can combine your two queries:

```
SELECT  Store.Store_ID, 
        Store.Store_Name,
        TopStore.StoreProducts,
        Vendor.Vendor_ID, 
        Vendor.Vendor_Name, 
        COUNT(Product.Product_ID) AS ItemsSuppliedToStore
FROM    ((((SELECT  TOP 1 
                    Store_ID, 
                    COUNT(Product_ID) AS StoreProducts
            FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT Store_ID, Product_ID
                        FROM    Item
                    ) i
            GROUP BY Store_ID
            ORDER BY COUNT(Product_ID) DESC
        ) AS TopStore
        INNER JOIN Store
            ON Store.Store_ID = TopStore.Store_ID)
        INNER JOIN Item
            ON Item.Store_ID = TopStore.Store_ID)
        INNER JOIN Product
            ON item.Product_ID = Product.Product_ID)
        INNER JOIN Vendor
            ON Vendor.Vendor_ID = Product.Vendor_ID
GROUP BY Store.Store_ID, Store.Store_Name, TopStore.StoreProducts, 
         Vendor.Vendor_ID, Vendor.Vendor_Name;
```